# Why does button click event not work when it is in a LinearLayout?

Tags: android

I have an oddity I can't figure out. With the layout below, the button click event that I've assigned does not work. Nothing happens when I tap the button.

(the layout is a bit more complex than this, but I've removed the irrelevant stuff):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutOverview"
    android:paddingLeft="7dp"
    android:paddingRight="7dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblOverviewText"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutSingleBlock"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblOverviewText"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutSetUnsetButtons"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <!-- irrelevant stuff removed --> 

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMyButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MY BUTTON" />       
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

However, if I move the button outside the context of the `LinearLayout`, e.g. below, it works.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutOverview"
    android:paddingLeft="7dp"
    android:paddingRight="7dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblOverviewText"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMyButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MY BUTTON" />                 
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutSingleBlock"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblOverviewText"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutSetUnsetButtons"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <!-- irrelevant stuff removed --> 

        <!-- button moved outside the LinearLayout --> 

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What is it about this `LinearLayout` that is preventing button click events?

**Edit**

as requested this is how I assign the click listener in `OnCreate`: (C#/Mono for Android)

```
FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnMyButton).Click += (s, e) => AlertAlarmEvents();
```

Just to note, this exact code works outside the context of the LinearLayout, but not inside, as is outlined in the question.

Comment: I think `irrelevant stuff` in your XML may be overlapping with the linear layout hence preventing the button from being clicked. Post full XML!

Comment: Try: 1. LinearLayout ll = findViewById ...
2. Button btn = ll.findViewById ...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot add `android:clickable="true"` to linearLayout, i think you mistook id's

Comment: I had that in previous attempts and it still didn't work. I'll try it again now and respond with the result.

Comment: In code, you change **android:visibility="gone"** to visible?

Comment: yes, I do. The layout & contents are definitely visible on the screen

Comment: You set to button (id=btnMyButton) click listener? Like: btnMyButton.setOnClickListener(...)? Please, show code.

Comment: confirming: adding `android:clickable="true"` to the layout doesn't do anything

Comment: Also, try rebuild & clean project please.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39907/discussion-between-kvirair-and-davedev)

Comment: I've updated the question with how the click event is assigned.